# Is there a way to hide my profile from Google search?

Tags: feature-request, google, profile-page

If you Google my name, it comes up with a link to my ServerFault profile first, then StackOverflow profile, then LinkedIn, then website, etc.

I've heard it's common practice for employers to Google your name, so I'd like the results to show the most relevant information. My ServerFault account contains nothing, and there's no reason for an employer to see my Meta profile (which is further down, but still on page 1). Having those links show up in the results isn't relevant or helpful to someone searching for information about me.

What I'd like is to prevent Google (and other search engines) from spidering/showing my *Overflow site profiles except StackOverflow, or be able to control this somehow per *Overflow site.

Honestly, I don't know if this is even possible, as I'm not familiar with SEO and such. I know this kind of thing would never work perfectly, but as long as it works for the major search engines, that's all that matters.

I suppose a way around this is to simply remove my name from the profiles I don't want to show up... but that doesn't *really* solve the problem. For example, I could end up building a good rep here on Meta, to which I would want to attach my name for other users to see, but is an employer (or anyone else in the general public, for that matter) really going to care about what goes on here? Highly unlikely. I think employers would be more interested in things that relate to the tasks for which I would be hired. It isn't important information even though it may be ranked higher on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link from your other sites (with `rel="me"` if you like) to your Stack Overflow profile and not the others.

Comment: People searching for information on me won't necessarily connect the dots between my user profiles, but this is a good idea, which I'll implement.

Comment: Accepted since it's the best answer right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I use a nickname online and only this nickname, although my profile does link my real name to my nickname. Fortunately, my real name is common enough in the Netherlands so possible employers will find many other persons instead of me. The nickname I use also contains two popular words/names to make it a bit difficult to find. I also use about 4 other nicknames that are not linked to my name or my SO nickname to post on some other sites.

A nickname will just make it a bit more difficult for employers to track you online. By using multiple nicknames and several email addresses, you can actually stay a bit more anonymous online.

I would suggest that you change your name in your SO profile to a nickname instead. (SeigelJon, for example. Or just mix the letters to generate a different word.) Google will soon "forget" about your old name being linked, thus when people search for "Jon Seigel", your own site will be the top one again.

Comment: I would need to use a nickname that doesn't contain the words of my name. I just tried Googling "jonseigel" and it was still smart enough to give me the same results as before, so I'm assuming that any single word combination of my name will show up as before, too.

Comment: Which is why I suggested "seigeljon" instead. :-) The top-2 links are your own home sites, with the second one being on your own domain and the first one related to an .edu domain.

Answer (score 2):

> I could end up building a good rep here on Meta, to which I would want to attach my name for other users to see, but is an employer (or anyone else in the general public, for that matter) really going to care about what goes on here?

This is how the Internet works. It does not distinguish random people from the potential employer. You should be careful about *everything* you do under your name on the Internet. If you don't want something to be seen by others associated with your name, then don't post it anywhere non-anonymously.

Comment: I figured someone might bring up this point, but edited out a disclaimer before posting my question. I don't have a problem associating my name with my posts. The thing is that some of the postings aren't going to be relevant to people searching on my name.

Answer (score 0):

> It isn't important information even
>   though it may be ranked higher on
>   Google.

A solution would be to get a job at Google and work on getting more relevant information in the search results. It's a bit of a work around though.

Comment: While I would love a job at Google, and this is a good idea, I don't think the idea is either feasible or possible without some kind of author input (which is essentially what I want).

Answer (score 0):

Change your name on the Trilogy sites?