# Stack exchange user pages and google

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, google

I am now finding a problem when someone googles for me.  Rather than finding my website, or LinkedIn page or Facebook page, they often get a complete page of links to the “users” pages for me on different Stack Exchange sites!

I have partly sorted this out, by removing my real name from the user pages on a lot of Stack Exchange sites.

*I don’t know the solution to this, but I don’t think the plan was to make googling for a person less useful!*

---

Part of the problem is that there are so many pages that point to the “user page” including all questions and answers.   But the link on the user page to your home page is marked so search engines don’t use it.

Maybe we need a checkbox on the “user page” to say “tell google to give this a low page rank”

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34450/is-there-a-way-to-hide-my-profile-from-google-search

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this fundamentally a Google problem? Their engine is returning useless information about you ahead of more relevant links. I don't think SE can really fix this, unless they completely exclude user pages from being crawled.

Comment: What I don't understand is why they won't entertain adding an option to do exactly that!